# Performance setup apache 2.4 with 1gb mariadb database

Tags: performance, apache-2.4

Hi i have vps with Centos 7 with 4gb of ram and 8cores. I have installed mariadb database and apache 2.4.

I want run prestashop on it. But I have database which has 1GB so If I want to show for example categories it show me this memory message :

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 256 bytes)
```

I know, I can allocate it but 3,5GB it's still nothing it wants more.. 
So my question is if I can somehow setup the apache for better performance or I need more GB of ram for example 8gb or 16gb ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: Is this error from starting mariadb or from PHP. If from PHP what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: There is whole message :   `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 3670016000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /var/www/html/flash-autodiely.sk/public_html/classes/db/DbPDO.php on line 164
[PrestaShop] Fatal error in module file :/var/www/html/flash-autodiely.sk/public_html/classes/db/DbPDO.php:
Allowed memory size of 3670016000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes)`

Comment: Wow, prestashop must be *really* bad, if it can't run within 3.5GB of memory per-process.  I'd suggest selecting a different ecommerce platform.